# How could I change a link on a webpage if the device is mobile? HTML/Javascript/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, href

I'm wanting to make it to where if the device is mobile (iPhone, Android, Windows, Etc.) it goes to a a different link than if it was a desktop device viewing the page.

For example, if I wanted to use an URL scheme to open instagram on a mobile device but the instagram website for a desktop device.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Ilan's code like this

```
<a href="javascript:testBrowser()>Link</a>
```

where `testBrowser()` is a function containing his code.

Comment: If the 'if' statement @Ilan provided returns 'true,' the 'window.location' becomes the mobile destination. Else it becomes the desktop destination.

Comment: You know, an upvote for my help wouldn't have hurt anyone haha.

Comment: sorry, I don't have 15 rep. yet :/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) && (window.location.href == "http://yourhomeurl.com"){
window.location = "http://yourredirecturl.com";
}
</script>
```

What it does: Detects the device the user is using and redirects them to the url (http://yourredirecturl.com)

Comment: I can see how this works but I'm not quite sure how to implement this into an <a href="">